# How would you write a method that takes a parameter like [ModelBinder(typeof(GeoPointModelBinder))] GeoPoint location

Tags: c#

I was reading an example about the ASP.NET Web API framework, and how you can create a modelbinder to bind parameters during a request.

My question is, how would you write a c# class/method to accept a parameter that looks like:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get([ModelBinder(typeof(GeoPointModelBinder))] GeoPoint location)
```

If you could briefly explain the syntax and the general idea behind it that would be great.

Reference: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: The line is 100% finished. ModelBinder - ModelBinderAttribute class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelbinderattribute(v=vs.118).aspx), GeoPointModelBinder - binder class, that you must create, GeoPoint - model class.

Comment: ModelBinderAttribute class has constructor that gets Type. You pass typeof(GeoModelBinder) there.

Comment: @Der_Meister what about the square brackets?

Comment: It's an attribute. Attributes can be set to classes, properties, fields and even parameters. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Test081204
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
    public class SomeCoolAttribute : System.Attribute
    {
        public readonly int Val;

        public SomeCoolAttribute(int val)
        {
            Val = val;
        }
    }

    class Test
    {
        public void Run([SomeCool(123)] string value)
        {
            // Prints "In Run: test123"
            Console.WriteLine("In Run: " + value);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var parameters = typeof(Test).GetMethod("Run").GetParameters();
            var attr = parameters[0].GetCustomAttribute(typeof(SomeCoolAttribute)) as SomeCoolAttribute;

            // Prints "123"
            Console.WriteLine("In Main: " + attr.Val);

            new Test().Run("test" + attr.Val.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ```[SomeCoole(123)] string value```  is 123 a default value?

Comment: No, it's a value passed to an attribute. F.e. HttpActionName("CustomName") attribute can be used in ASP.NET MVC controller to set a different action name for method.